# Ruby on Rails - login implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

generic question from someone trying to learn the Rails framework. I have a web app that I need to implement a login system into (not authentication, just login). I have multiple pages within my app, each with separate tables and stuff that needs to be saved to each particular user. I know I need to use the sessions resource somehow, but I'm not entirely clear on what I need to add. I know it's not a very specific question, so any info at all on how to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by not authentication? Don't you want the user to input email and password and verify the user for your app? If the user input his/her credentials and login then all the queries and changes in the database will be done relative to that user.

Comment: I am not sure how you login without authenticating.  Be that as it may, the [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) will add user login/authentication to your site.  If you want to roll your own (and I recommend you do if you are learning) check out the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/).

Comment: do you mean 'authorisation' not 'authentication'?

Comment: I am stupid, yes I meant authorization.